# Python 3 cant update tkinter label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

First of all, I know that there are tons of threads about this issue, but I have still made 0 progress on this, none of the solutions work. I even created a minimal example with 9 lines of code and doesnt matter what I do, the label text wont change:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry("500x50" + "+" + str(screen_width - 520) + "+" + str(screen_height - 140))
root.title("POE Price Checker")
rootLabelHeader = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Currently searching:").pack()

labelText = tkinter.StringVar()
labelText.set("Nothing")
rootLabelInfo = tkinter.Label(root, text = labelText.get(), width=90).pack()

#rootLabelInfo.configure(text="New String") # Nope
#rootLabelInfo.config(text="New String") # Nope

labelText.set("Doesnt Work")
labelText.get()

#root.after(1000, ListenToInput)
root.mainloop()
```

First I have tried using `StringVar`, but nothing happens, it never changes the text to "Doesnt Work", also no errors are shown.

Then I tried using:

```
rootLabelInfo.configure(text="New String")
rootLabelInfo.config(text="New String")
```

Both give me `NoneType object has no attribute config`.

Comment: `rootLabelHeader = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Currently searching:")` ; `rootLabelHeader.pack()` now can configure the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rootLabelInfo = tkinter.Label(root, text = labelText.get(), width=90).pack()` stores the packed object function (which will return `None`) to `rootLabelInfo`

If you plan on using the widget later, do it in two lines:

```
rootLabelInfo = tkinter.Label(root, text = labelText.get(), width=90)
rootLabelInfo.pack()
```

Another method is using a `StringVar` and setting the `textvariable` attribute:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry("500x50" + "+" + str(screen_width - 520) + "+" + str(screen_height - 140))
root.title("POE Price Checker")
rootLabelHeader = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Currently searching:").pack()

labelText = tkinter.StringVar()
labelText.set("Nothing")
print(labelText.get())
rootLabelInfo = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = labelText, width=90).pack()

labelText.set("New String")
print(labelText.get())

#root.after(1000, ListenToInput)
root.mainloop()
```